# How to get network/subnet and nexthop from a routing table txt

Tags: python, regex, ip

Below is a network device routing table:

```
destination         nexthop                 metric flags     interface       
0.0.0.0/0           192.168.86.1            10     A S       ethernet1/1
10.1.1.0/26         192.168.86.81           10     A S       ethernet1/1
1.1.1.1/32          192.168.86.191          0      A C       ethernet1/1
```

How can I use regex to match string with format network/subnet-mask (ie. `0.0.0.0/0, 10.1.1.0/26, 1.1.1.1/32` in this example)?
I tried the following. It doesn't work:

```
import re
ip_with_mask = re.search(r'((2[0-5]|1[0-9]|[0-9])?[0-9]\.){3}((2[0-5]|1[0-9]|[0-9])?[0-9])/(^[1-9]$|^[1-2][0-9]$|^3[0-2]$)', oneline).group()
```

`((2[0-5]|1[0-9]|[0-9])?[0-9]\.){3}((2[0-5]|1[0-9]|[0-9])?[0-9])` is the ip address.
/ is between network and subnet mask.
`^[0-9]$|^[1-2][0-9]$|^3[0-2]`$ is 0-32 subnet mask number.

What's wrong with this regex?

Comment: I dont think `regex` is the right choice here. What are you looking to achieve?

Comment: I want to get the following result and save to a csv file:
0.0.0.0/0,192.168.86.1
10.1.1.0/26,192.168.86.81
1.1.1.1/32,192.168.86.191

Comment: How are you retrieving the data? Can you include the code to retrieve the route table?

Comment: I'm using netmiko SSH to the Palo Alto VM firewall, do 'show routing route'.

connection = ConnectHandler(**device_dict)
with open(routing-table.txt", 'w') as writefile:        
    output = connection.send_command('show routing route')
    writefile.write(output)
    writefile.write('\n')
connection.disconnect()

Comment: why are you using end-of-line `$` sign inside your subnet mask definition?

Comment: '^[1-9]$|^[1-2][0-9]$|^3[0-2]$' means 0-32. It's the network bits of a subnet mask.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use regex here. You have a fixed width format, so why not try to use a tool (e.g. Python) to parse that format for you?

Try this:

```py
import io
import pandas


# You can also read this from file, I'm using an in-memory file just for demo purposes
table = io.StringIO(
    """destination         nexthop                 metric flags     interface       
0.0.0.0/0           192.168.86.1            10     A S       ethernet1/1
10.1.1.0/26         192.168.86.81           10     A S       ethernet1/1
1.1.1.1/32          192.168.86.191          0      A C       ethernet1/1
"""
)

# Read a dataframe from a Fixed Width Format (fwf)
df: pandas.DataFrame = pandas.read_fwf(table)

# Show as CSV
print(df.to_csv(index=False))
```

Output:

```
destination,nexthop,metric,flags,interface
0.0.0.0/0,192.168.86.1,10,A S,ethernet1/1
10.1.1.0/26,192.168.86.81,10,A S,ethernet1/1
1.1.1.1/32,192.168.86.191,0,A C,ethernet1/1
```

Comment: Brilliant! Much appreciated for your post.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex works:

```
([2][5][0-5]\.|[2][0-4][0-9]\.|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]\.){3}([2][5][0-5]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])/([3][0-2]|[2][0-9]|[1][0-9]|[0-2])
```